# Why do i have this error with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a scatterplot of some data in matplotlib using:

```
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='r', marker='0')
```

However, I'm getting the error below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\K\Desktop\3d", line 11, in <module>
    ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='r', marker='0')
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 2180, in scatter
    patches = Axes.scatter(self, xs, ys, s=s, c=c, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 6296, in scatter
    marker_obj = mmarkers.MarkerStyle(marker)
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.py", line 162, in __init__
    self.set_marker(marker)
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.py", line 233, in set_marker
    Path(marker)
    File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 147, in __init__
    assert vertices.ndim == 2
    AssertionError
```

What am I missing? I can't see anything wrong.

Comment: Please show some minimal code to reproduce these errors if you want any help.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem appears to be due to mistaking `0` for `o`.

Try `ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='r', marker='o')`  (instead of `marker='0'`).

If you pass in a maker that isn't one of matplotlib's marker codes, it assumes that you're passing in an array of vertices that can be converted into a path that can be used as a marker.  Thus the somewhat cryptic error you're receiving.

If you want a literal `0` as the marker, use `marker='$0$'`. The dollar signs indicate a latex-formatted string, which matplotlib will use as the marker.